# Adding another sub-menu to existing code

Tags: python

The code below has a main menu and a sub menu.  The first menu prompts on load and selecting an option will load another "page" with more options.  I cannot figure out how to get to another sub section from here.  Called sub2 for example.

Lets say when Option 1 is selected it will prompt you two choose two sub options option1_sub2_1 and option1_sub2_2.

Lets say when you select Option 2 it prompts for option2_sub2_1 option2_sub2_2

I have one set of options stored as:
    menu_actions = {
'main_menu': main_menu,
'1': one,
'2': two,
'b': back,
'q': exit,
}

It is possible to have it setup somehow like this:
    option1_sub2 = {
    '1': one,
    '2': two,
    }
and
    option2_sub2 = {
    '1': one,
    '2': two,
    }

That way I can re-use the same numbers for the different sub2 items.  Is this possible?

This is my first code project and I have not been able to make it past this part. Any help would be appreciated.

The code:

```
import sys, os

# Main definition - constants
menu_actions  = {}

# =======================
#     MENUS FUNCTIONS
# =======================
# Main menu (display list on screen)
def main_menu():
    os.system('clear')

    print "1. Option"
    print "2. Option"

    choice = raw_input(" >>  ")
    exec_menu(choice)
    return
# Choose a menu
def exec_menu(choice):
os.system('clear')
ch = choice.lower()
if ch == '':
    menu_actions['main_menu']()
else:
    try:
        menu_actions[ch]()
    except KeyError:
        print "Invalid selection, please try again.\n"
        menu_actions['main_menu']()
return
# =======================
#       SUB MENUS
# =======================
# Back to main menu
def back():
menu_actions['main_menu']()
# Exit program
def exit():
    sys.exit()
# Option1
def one():
    print "Option 1"
    print (30 * '-')
    print "Sub Option 1"
    print "Sub Option 2"
    print "[B]ack"
    print "[Q]uit"
    choice = raw_input(" >>  ")
    exec_menu(choice)
    return
# FTP
def two():
    print (30 * '-')
    print "Sub Option 1"
    print "Sub Option 2"
    print "[B]ack"
    print "[Q]uit"
    choice = raw_input(" >>  ")
    exec_menu(choice)
    return
# =======================
#    MENUS DEFINITIONS
# =======================
# Menu definition
menu_actions = {
    'main_menu': main_menu,
    '1': one,
    '2': two,
    'b': back,
    'q': exit,
}
# =======================
#      MAIN PROGRAM
# =======================
# Main Program
if __name__ == "__main__":
        # Launch main menu
    main_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

start by abstracting it out

first create a method that will continually prompt for input until a given input result is achieved

```
 def input_option(prompt,options):
     while True:
           result = raw_input(prompt)
           if result in option: return result
           print "Invalid Option Selected %r"%result
```

test this function with things like `print input_option("Enter 1 or 2 or Three",["1","2","Three"])`

now abstract out a function to display a menu and get input from the menu

```
 def select_menu(options):
     print "Select From the choices Below:"
     options = []
     for option_text,input_value in options:
          print option_text
          options.append(input_value)

     return input_option(">>>",options)
```

you can test this like

```
options = [("1> option 1","1"),("2> option 2","2")]
print select_menu(options)
options2 = [("[B]ack","B"),("[Q]uit","Q")]
print select_menu(options2)
```

then all you have to do is tie it together by mapping actions to inputs

```
menu_otions  = [("Show Menu [1]","1"),("Show Menu [2]","2"),("[Q]uit","Q")]
menu_actions = {"1":show_menu1,"2":show_menu2,"Q":sys.exit
```